# black background (opacity 0.6) after an image background, and text is opacity 1

Tags: html, css, opacity

[Here is an example](http://www.formget.com/css-background-opacity/)

As you see the tutorial, there got 3 different opacity picture which are 0.2, 0.6, and 1.
Notice at the opacity=0.2, the background is totally white, but what i want is opacity more to black. 
and the text i want is white. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity means more or less transparent, so for the desired effect, use a dark background with opacity 0.9 or put a dark layer under the 0.2 opacity layer

Comment: while i put a dark layer , the text is inherited and become 0.2 also. i want a dark layer 0.2 with text 1.0. any links can helps ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the parent div background color to black, and for the text is just setting "color" CSS property to white. I hope it can help.